# Lan/ethernet port issue

Tags: internet, lan

Internet cable when plugged in the lan port at the back of pc,it is either showing disconnected (red cross)or its detecting after a several seconds and the green light is off,only yellow one is blinking!Is this a hardware issue?Direct connection,no modem or router.
Drivers are updated.Win 10x64.Realtek inbuilt ethernet controller.

Comment: Direct connection to what device?

Comment: PC(motherboard)

Comment: Does it work when connected to another device? What's on the other end of the connection?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the LAN cable is the culprit. First try a different cable.

If changing the cable doesn't make a difference and the modem/router has more than 1 ports, try a different port. If it works, the previous port is faulty.
If not, try plugging to another device (PC, laptop etc). If it works, then there is a problem with the ethernet controller of the PC (drivers, configuration...). If not, there is a problem with the modem/router.

Comment: Pretty succinct... but you missed the 5 buck life-saver... a can of contact cleaner ;)